# how to edit the text of row in jQuery +JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am creating a demo in which I make row in button click .I want to edit it's text  when I click generated row "it generate another row inside container".can we give a option to change the text of row while clicking the edit button .It some thing open pop up when your press done it save the text on same id ?

http://jsfiddle.net/k7zJ4/2/

```
function createTestCase(testCaseName,iscreatedFromScript,jsonObject) {

    var id;
    if (typeof ($("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id')) == 'undefined') {
        id = "tc_1";
    } else {
        id = $("#testCaseContainer li:last").attr('id');
        var index = id.indexOf("_");
        var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
        count = parseInt(count);
        id = id.substring(0, index) + "_" + parseInt(count + 1);
    }
    var html = '<div class="testcaselist_row">' + '<ul>' + '<li id="' + id + '" class="clickTestCaseRow"><a href="#" style="color: #ffffff!important;">' + testCaseName + '</a><a class="delete deleteTestCase_h"></a><button class="editclass" style="width:200px !important">edit</button ></li>' + '</ul>' + '</div>';
    $('#testCaseContainer').append(html);

    var elem = document.getElementById('testCaseContainer'); // just to scroll down the line
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below sample code that will replicate the scenario you want to achieve in your code using jqm.Save the below code as html and click on add text case and click on change text button

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>My Page</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page">

   <div data-role=" content ">
   <div class="contentsubbox" id="testCaseContainer">
   <div class="testcaselist_row"><ul  id="testCaseLists" data-role="listview" data-theme="a"></ul></div>
 </div>
 </div>

 <footer id="firstPageFooter">
    <button class="addtestbtn" id="addTestCase" data-theme="a" style="color: #ffffff!important;">Add Test Case</button>

 </footer>
 </div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});

$('#addTestCase').click(function () {

    createTestCase("trdt",false,null);

});
$('#testCaseLists').delegate('li', 'tap', function () {
console.log('put your text changing logic here');
$(this).find('a:first').text('text u want to change');//text function shud contain the text
});

function createTestCase(testCaseName,iscreatedFromScript,jsonObject) {
console.log("create test case");
var id;
if ($("div.contentsubbox").find("ul li").length == 0){
    id = "tc_1";
} else {
    id = $("#testCaseContainer").find("ul li:last").attr('id');
    var index = id.indexOf("_");
    var count = id.substring(index + 1, id.length);
    count = parseInt(count);
    id = id.substring(0, index) + "_" + parseInt(count + 1);
}

var html = "<li id="+ id +" class='clickTestCaseRow'><a href='#' style='color:   #ffffff!important;'>" + testCaseName + "</a><a class='delete deleteTestCase_h'></a><button class='editclass' style='width:200px !important'>Change text</button ></li>";
$('#testCaseLists').append(html);
$('#testCaseLists').listview('refresh');
var elem = document.getElementById('testCaseContainer'); // just to scroll down the line
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;



 }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Add comments if you need further help.

Comment: I am just asking why it is not working on my fiddle

Comment: Dude.you haven't mentioned that in your question !!! While creating a question pls be specific on what you need.